# Updating variable of View Controller using App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I am basically trying to display the push notification received in the application. 
I am trying to update the text of a view controller when a notification is received. However, every time I try to update the view controller, I get an error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Here is my appdelegate snippet:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.

    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")



    let vc = FirstViewController()


    vc.notificationText = "Test"
    print (vc.notificationText)
    vc.updateText()

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
}
```

Here is my View Controller:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var notificationLabel: UILabel!
var notificationText = "No notifications"

@IBAction func logOut(sender: AnyObject) {
    try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
    LogOutComplete()
}

func LogOutComplete() {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let logIn : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LogIn") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(logIn, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    notificationLabel.text = notificationText

    //notificationLabel.text = notificationText
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

/*override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    notificationLabel.text = notificationText
}*/

func updateText () {
    notificationLabel.text = notificationText
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

I really don't know why it is giving me this error. Maybe someone could explain and help me with the solution. All help is appreciated!

Comment: are you using the interface builder?

Comment: @Kex Storyboard? Yes

Comment: @NathanModern Its because you are not making an object from storyboard for the viewcontroller. Do you want this view controller to be opened when push arrives or are you there on this view controller itself when push arrive

Comment: you are creating a view controller in app main but you aren't actually referencing the one that's created in the storyboard.

Comment: I want the View Controller to update when the push notification is received for when the app is active and when the application is closed. I want it to display the notification text. I have the storyboard one connected to the ViewController. @Kex

Comment: @NathanModern Check my approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited for Swift 2.2:**

You are creating a new instance of `FirstViewController` in the `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification` method. So you are updating the property of a different instance of `FirstViewController` than you are meaning to. The one you are updating is not being displayed. The error is coming because `updateText()` is being called but the storyboard isn't initialized so notificationLabel is still nil.

To do what you are trying to, instead pass the notification to the view controller using a notification post and have `FirstViewController` added as an observer:

In your `AppDelegate`, change the body to the following:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
             fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
// If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
// this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
// TODO: Handle data of notification

// Print message ID.

print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "Add_Notification_Post_Name_Here", object: nil,
                                                              userInfo: userInfo)
```

}

In `FirstViewController`, add an observer to listen for notification posts:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Some_Method_Name:, name: "Add_Notification_Post_Name_Here", object: nil)
}
```

In `FirstViewController`, add a method to handle this notification post:

```
func Some_Method_Name(_ notification: NSNotification) {

guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {
        return
    }
    guard let payload = userInfo["Some_Message_Key_Here"] as? NSString  else {
        return
    }
    notificationText = String(payload)
    updateText()
}
```

This method converts your package to a payload of type String to assign to your notification text. Then you call your updateText() function.

Comment: @Ian Moses This will create a new controller everytime even if app is active

Comment: @NathanModern This is perhaps a proper way to have a view controller handle notifications received from appDelegate.

Comment: @IanMoses where would I add the viewController observer?

Comment: I generally add observers in my view controller's viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Can you convert that to swift 2.2?

Comment: @NathanModern I have posted in 2.2 only after looking at your code

Comment: @NathanModern Sure thing. What lines are erroring for you?

Comment: func Some_Method_Name(_ notification: Notification) { it is saying Notification is undeclared type

Comment: Try NSNotification instead of Notification

Comment: Does not work. It doesn't update it when notification received.

Comment: Can you throw in a print line and confirm if you are successfully running the func Some_Method_Name(_ notification:) I want to see where it's erroring.

Comment: There is no print coming back :/

Comment: May be the addObserver line (different in Swift 3). See edits.

Comment: Same goes for postNotification line syntax.

Comment: That worked really well. Will this work if application is not running and notification is clicked?

Comment: Yes, I believe this works if application is in background.

Comment: But what if application is not in background?

Comment: Works for that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. I had a bunch of trouble with this myself.

Comment: @NathanModern It will not work when app is killed. As you need to obtain the launch options dictionary

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari is correct. I mistook your question for meaning in the foreground (not in the background). You need to be a VoiP app in order for notifications to work when app is force quit. All non-VoiP apps face this problem on iPhone.